# Re.search for comma/delimiter-removed substring

Tags: python, regex

I have a text and used a function to extract a part of the text. However, in the returned value, delimiters (e.g ',', '-') are removed. I need to find the extracted part in the original text including substring and position.
e.g:

```
original_text = "xyz, 19900 Praha 9, Letnany"
(or original_text = "xyz, 19900 Praha 9 - Letnany")
extracted_text = "praha 9 letnany" (lower case, delimiters are removed)
```

I expect the output is the same as the ouput of re.search('praha 9, letnany', original_text) meaning getting the substring 'Praha 9, Letnany' and start of the match: 11.

Is there any regular expression to locate extracted text in the original text?

- The output of the function can't be changed (up until now)
- I have tried to find problems related to ignoring some character while using regex but their problems are different.

Comment: Using `re.split(r'(your_delimiter)', your_string)` will select the delimiter in the output list. What is the desired output on your example ?

Comment: To confirm: you need to find where string2, ignoring case and adding delimiters anywhere and in any amount, can be found in string1?

Comment: @AlexandreB. I have edited the question. Is that clear?

Comment: @ScottHunter can be understood like that :)

Comment: This is confusing. After reading this question multiple times, I am not able to understand what the actual problem is, what is the significance of the last two list points in question and what should be the desired output? Just post input, what output you are getting and what should be desired output.

Comment: Totally unclear.

Answer (score 2):

This will locate a span in the original text that matches the extracted text ignoring case & inserting delimiters at will (in this case, comma or dash):

```
import re

pat = ("[,-]*".join(list(extracted_text))).replace(" ","\\s")

mat = re.search( pat, original_text, re.I )
if mat:
    print(mat.span())
else:
    print("No match")
```

Comment: should edit your pattern, it lacks a space after '-' but your code is much more compact than mine :)

Comment: @Hien.Ha: Space wasn't listed as a delimiter; spaces being present in the result where (it is claimed) delimiters have been removed supports space *not* being a delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

Same idea as @ScottHunter but process at word level instead of character level:

```
import re

ori_txt  = '19900, Praha 7, Letnany'
extr_txt = 'praha 7 letnany'

delimiters = [',', '\s', '-']

deli = '|'.join([i for i in delimiters])
extr_arr = re.split(deli, extr_txt)

ins_c = ''.join([i for i in delimiters])
ins_c = ''.join(['[', ins_c, ']', '*'])

pat = ins_c.join(extr_arr)
mat = re.search(pat, ori_txt, re.I)
if mat:
    print mat.group()
else:
    print('not found')
```

I first want to find a regular expression to directly search for the extracted text in the original text but there seem to be no such an expression. Here is another way to solve my problem. Thank you.